# Get difference between two character codes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ascii

Although it might not be readable, I am hoping that someone can tell me if it is possible - and if so how - to make the following code work

```
true if (string1 - string2) == predefined_distance
```

I would hope this might be possible using Ruby's Open Classes, but looking at the documentation for UTF-8 and `Encoder::Converter` I'm not sure if it's actually possible to do do anything more than `<=>` which isn't at all precise.  Perhaps we can convert to ASCII and compare those values?

An example of use might be to compare two opening an closing brackets, to see if they match instead of defining separate lists or containers for each type of bracket, and instead we can just define a distance for any two arbitrary characters.

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted.  it is perfectly fine.  I am upvoting to offset.

Comment: SO tends to be a hostile place, so thanks!

Comment: The UTF-8/ASCII distance between the various bracket types is not constant, e.g. `(` and `)` have a distance of 1, whereas `[` and `]` have a distance of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in method  `ord` of  String  class can return number of the character:

```
true if (string1.chars.first.ord - string2.chars.first.ord) == predefined_distance
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ord

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't see this method in the String documentation, sorry!

Comment: You can just write `string1.ord` instead of `string1.chars.first.ord`.

Answer (score 1):

What is it you want to accomplish?  Did you really just want to check the first character in the string?  Also, regarding ASCII values, there are many character sets in the world that do not use ASCII and even require multiple bytes per character.  So it would be important to ensure you are operating on characters and not bytes. Here's an example using the word 'ruby' in Japanese, in irb:

```
2.3.0 :018 > s = 'ルビー'
 => "ルビー"
2.3.0 :019 > s.chars
 => ["ル", "ビ", "ー"]
2.3.0 :020 > s.chars.size
 => 3
2.3.0 :021 > s.bytes
 => [227, 131, 171, 227, 131, 147, 227, 131, 188]
2.3.0 :022 > s.bytes.size
 => 9
2.3.0 :023 > s.chars.first.ord.to_s(16)
 => "30eb"
```